# Calling functions in NIntegrate which contain NIntegrate itself

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following integration scheme where I am interested in the values of `j[x]`:

```
f[x]=NIntegrate[...]
g[x]=NIntegrate[...]
h[x]=f[x]/g[x]
j[x]=NIntegrate[h[x]*...]
```

I want to know how one would properly define the functions in Mathematica to not unnecessarily call any of the functions.

So far I tried the following

```
f[x_NumericQ]:=f[x]=NIntegrate[...]
g[x_NumericQ]:=g[x]=NIntegrate[...]
h[x_NumericQ]:=h[x]=f[x]/g[x]
j[x_NumericQ]:=j[x]=NIntegrate[h[x]*...]
```

By using memorization at least the second evaluation is fast. But what I am more interested in is whether this is the correct form to define functions which contain `NIntegrate` and are later called by another function.

Besides, I wonder whether it is better in terms of computation time to manually define the integration range if I have an integration range of `-Infinity,Infinity` when the integrand is a fast decaying function.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should show the functions you are integrating

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the various integrands, I would recommend

```
Clear[f, g, h, j]
f[x_] = NIntegrate[...];
g[x_] = NIntegrate[...];
h[x_NumericQ] = f[x]/g[x];
j[x_] = NIntegrate[h[x]* ...]
```

This assumes that the integrands of in definitions of `f` and `g` don't contain singularities, that they don't appear directly in last integral, and that each call to `NIntegrate` actually evaluates.

Comment: As soon as I remove the SetHold `:=` in f[x] the message `The Integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values...` Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: [Edit]: As soon as I remove the SetHold `:=` in f[x] the message `The Integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values...` as `x` (the argument of the function) is NOT the integration variable.

Comment: @DisplayName. Since I have no access to the details of your code, I have nothing more to say.